# Email Sending not working in CentOS 7 but same credentials works on localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I created an email account on godaddy which works perfectly on server and on localhost. When I did the testing on Linode server using the same email credentials. It did not work and gave 500 Internal Server Error.

> Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host
>   sg6plcpnl0067.prod.sin3.secureserver.net [ #0]

Am I missing something?

**.env details**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sg6plcpnl0067.prod.sin3.secureserver.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@myserver.in
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_NAME=myserver
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@myserver.in
```

Comment: Try with this `'encryption' => ssl,
'port' => 465,`

Comment: Updated the question with more details. Please let me know if you need more details

Comment: try to change `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` to `MAIL_DRIVER=mail` !